# Best way to implement ACL with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have my data model already defined and implemented. I can very easily write manually the filter to filter out non-authorized results for the user who sent the query (which would be in the style of: `"collection.acl.personId": queryPersonId` )

My problem is, where and how should I write this "thing" to be as automatic as possible?
I tried to do it with a custom query and a static method, but did not had any luck on both.

Static method con: I don't want to rewrite all my code to use .then(). I want to keep the current chaining.
Custom query: it simply did not worked, even by following the doc.

Ideal the result would be something like

```
Model.findWithAcl(filters).lean()
Model.findOneWithAcl(filters).lean()
```

Note that we are using Typescript. The priority would be to have something working, but having the ability to have a working type would be the second priority right after.

Thanks for any help

Comment: ACL is typically done by users and privileges (roles in MonogDB) Why do you want to set it in the query. It would be trivial to bypass your ACL.

Comment: The query is identified by Auth0, so I have the user identity secured in the token, not just passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casl mongoose gives a very good way of filtering both results (row level) and fields from collections. Note that it also can be used in the front end.

Great package that works very well with auth0 rights.

https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/intro
https://casl.js.org/v5/en/package/casl-mongoose